# Can't access Oracle Apex loging page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-ords, oracle-apex-18.2

Im installing oracle apex 18.2 in my 12c database. I've completed the instalation, changed admin password, ran apex_epg_config and unlocked the accounts. Im also running apex in the port 8080, but localhost:8080/apex wont load. (neither /apex_admin). What can I do?

[image: I get this]

I have also checked the parameters [image: parameters]

Comment: What does this return? `SELECT DBMS_XDB.GETHTTPPORT FROM DUAL;`

Comment: SQL> select dbms_xdb.gethttpport from dual;

GETHTTPPORT
-----------
       8080

SQL>

Comment: That looks OK. Did you try to **reboot** the computer?

Comment: I've rebooted and still the same

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any other idea. What you did (i.e. described) seems to be OK. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: two things, apex 18 is 5+ years old, and the epg is no longer supported for apex, you need to install and run ORDS for apex web access